# Syncing divergent local changes with git remote / master

Tags: git, github

I have a single remote repo and a few computers that can `pull` and `push` from the remote.  The versions on the two boxes frequently diverge -- I am wondering if it's possible to merge local changes to a `master` when these local versions and the remote / `master` version diverge?

I often forget to `push` from my laptop to the remote before i start working on the version that's on my desktop, and at present i resolve these problems with a reluctant:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

And some cut and pasting (it usually happens when edits are small, so it's not too burdensome).

What i would *love* to do is to merge the lagging version with the one on the remote.

I am sure this is possible, but i cannot figure it out (the online help i've found assumes you have a single box that's linked to the repo - not two divergent versions and one repo).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't use github, I do this sort of thing on my own systems.  There are a bunch of different ways to handle it.

Suppose you have a laptop and a desktop, and you use both.  You can:

```
laptop$ git remote add desktop ssh://desktop.host.name/...
```

and:

```
desktop$ git remote add laptop ssh://laptop.host.name/...
```

Now on either system (with non-bare repo) you can `git fetch laptop` or `git fetch desktop` as needed.  Occasionally you'll need to ssh from one to the other and `git commit` to save work-dir work so that it can be `fetch`ed easily.  So, you're at the desktop and realize you have not yet brought work over from the laptop.  `ssh laptop` and commit if needed, then `git fetch laptop`.  Now you have `laptop/branch` on your desktop and can `git merge` or `git cherry-pick` or whatever you want to do.  (You may have to go power up your laptop first. :-) )

Or, suppose you have a remote bare "sharing" repo named `origin`, and you are at your desktop and realize you forgot to push from the laptop.  Just ssh in to the laptop, commit if needed, `git push` to the bare repo, and then "git fetch" from the desktop to bring it back.  It's a bit more round-trip-ish but the result is the same, it is just named `origin/branch` instead of `laptop/branch`.

---

Edit: here are several common scenarios (made up just now, on the fly, so not very complicated).  Note, "lola" (which appears repeatedly below) is an alias:

```
$ git config --get alias.lola
log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
```

(Also note that I *have not* set up the desktop and laptop systems to have each other as "tracking" branches here.  I'm doing everything in "full manual mode".  I could configure, on the desktop, `branch.master.remote laptop` and `branch.master.merge refs/heads/master`; and do the same on the laptop but with the `remote` being `desktop`.  That would get me some automation—and in this posting, at least, I want to show the underlying mechanics, so I *don't* want any automation here.)

You're at the desktop and have done `cd project` to start working on it, and have started looking and realized: oh wait, I committed something on the laptop that I want to have over here.  I'm working on the branch `master` (it's a new project, there are no other branches yet).

So:

```
desktop$ git fetch laptop
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
[snip]
desktop$ git lola
* d824ebf (laptop/master) work done on laptop
* 176af7a (HEAD, master) initial
```

Here `laptop` has one commit that I don't.  If I have a bit of work I want to save I'll probably just use `git stash` (although there are other options).  In this case I have not even started work, as I noticed that foo.py is missing.

```
desktop$ git merge laptop/master
Updating 176af7a..d824ebf
Fast-forward
 foo.py |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo.py
```

Now laptop and desktop are in sync (although machine "laptop" doesn't know it!).  I work some more on foo.py and commit, getting `desktop` ahead.

Later, back on the laptop, I do:

```
laptop$ git fetch desktop
remote: Counting objects ...[snip]
$ git lola
* 968cf90 (desktop/master) main: fix stupid bug
* b8a9735 add main
* 6289ce6 fix up foo
* d824ebf (HEAD, master) work done on laptop
* 176af7a initial
```

So now if I `git merge desktop/master` I'll be all set to work more on the laptop:

```
laptop$ git merge desktop/master
Updating d824ebf..968cf90
Fast-forward
 foo.py  |  8 +++++++-
 main.py | 21 +++++++++++++++++++++
 2 files changed, 28 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 create mode 100644 main.py
```

It's a little messier if I've done work on both laptop and desktop and need to merge or rebase.  I'll probably rebase, I like my linear commit histories when I can get them :-) :

```
desktop$ ... work, commit, etc
# oops, I forgot to bring over stuff from laptop!
desktop$ git fetch laptop
remote: Counting objects [snip]
desktop$ git lola
* 8f95602 (HEAD, master) describe
| * bd5d378 (laptop/master) hook up function
|/  
* 968cf90 main: fix stupid bug
* b8a9735 add main
* 6289ce6 fix up foo
* d824ebf work done on laptop
* 176af7a initial
desktop$ git rebase laptop/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: describe
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging main.py
desktop$ git lola
* dba0f92 (HEAD, master) describe
* bd5d378 (laptop/master) hook up function
* 968cf90 main: fix stupid bug
* b8a9735 add main
* 6289ce6 fix up foo
* d824ebf work done on laptop
* 176af7a initial
```

Voila, git managed to do the right thing when I rebased (no merge conflicts or anything, result works, etc) and I'm back to a linear sequence.

In more complex projects I might decide at some point to restructure a bunch of commits and make a bit of a mess, and then I might use `git reset --hard`.  But then I need to know exactly what I'm doing, and which machine has which commits.  I must make sure that, wherever I am working (desktop, laptop, whatever) I have `fetch`ed all the other work-sites and incorporated all the "wanted" commits.  Restructuring—merging commits, applying "fixup"s in `rebase -i`, and so on—will make things hard for myself if I forget to bring over all the commits first.

If I'm the only one working on this (and just using two or three systems) it's not too bad; but if it's a shared project, I have to make sure I don't screw things up for others—especially if I'm using a `push` repo to transfer objects around, and sometimes deliberately `push -f` to rewrite the branch on the "transfer" repo.

Comment: thanks, that should help me avoid my present situation. Currently, i'm stuck as the tip of my local (laptop) branch is ahead of the remote -- do i just have to `reset --hard`?

Comment: You *can* use `reset`, but that's a bit of a sledgehammer approach to something that should need only a light tap. :-)  If `laptop/foo` has commits you want, you can `merge`, `cherry-pick`, `rebase`, etc., to pick them up.